# Error on my code

Tags: bash, awk

```
#!/bin/bash

# When a match is not found, just present nothing.
shopt -s nullglob

files=(*.wav)

if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
echo "No match found."
fi

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
# We get the date part
find_date=$(stat -c %y $file | awk '{print $1}')`
for t in "${parts[@]}"; do
IFS="-." read -ra parts <<< "$file"
  if [[ $t == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] ]]; then
        file_date=$t
        break
    fi
done
 # If a value was not assigned, then show an error message and continue to the next     file.
# Just making sure there is nothing in Array and date before it moves on
if [[ -z $file_date ]]; then

    continue
fi

file_year=${file_date:0:4}
file_month=${file_date:6:2}
mkdir -p "$file_year/$file_month"

# -- is just there to not interpret filenames starting with - as options.

echo "Moving: ./"$file "to: " "./"$file_year"/"$file_month
mv  "$file" "$file_year/$file_month"

done
```

I have some files that are .wav.... I want to put the files in an array like I did and then Stat -c %y filename |awk $1 which gives me YYYY-MM-DD and then I wanna put the date in the array so then I can set it 2 variables Year and Month so then I can either make a DIR Year/Month or if DIR is already there then just mv it. which is mkdir -p... Geting errors in my code but I do not think i am reading the file in my array correct.

25: continue: only meaningful in a `for',`while', or `until' loop
my echo statement Moving: ./OUT117-20092025-5845.wav to:  .//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides some syntax issues main problem is that you cannot have `continue` outside for loop.

Syntax error are:

- You cannot have space on either side of assignment operator `=` so `find_date= stat -c %y $file | awk`{print $1}`` ` should be ``find_date=$(stat -c %y $file | awk '{print $1}')`
- Regex operator is `=~` instead of `==`

**UPDATE:** You are starting your for loop before you are setting your variable.

```
for t in "${parts[@]}"; do
IFS="-." read -ra parts <<< "$file"
```

It should be:

```
IFS="-." read -ra parts <<< "$file"
for t in "${parts[@]}"; do
```

Comment: what would be some syntax issues.. I am very new to this

Comment: ./awktest.sh: line 14: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
./awktest.sh: line 39: syntax error: unexpected end of file              I edit the code above just now and ran it

Comment: for EX this is my test file 20010301.wav

Comment: So on line 14 there was a ` I removed and ran my code fine but it did not do anything

Comment: no, no more but my code is not doing anything at all. I do not know what issue would be

Comment: @Ryan: I can help you solving specific problems but difficult for me to write full script.